# ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain Dynamic Variable

Tags: apache, cookies

I need to consume some rest APIs, located in the domain A, from domain B. 
The login service is responsible to set the cookie. Using a Proxy I'm able to access the domain A from B with no problem.

Unfortunately, inspecting the response header, the cookie domain is set to A, where the services are located at, thus the browser doesn't store the cookies in the domain B, where the service is called from.

In the production env this is not a problem since the frontend and the backend are under the same domain. However, when working locally, the frontend is on localhost and the backend inside a virtual machine.

The only way I found to set the cookie to another domain is the apache directive `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain`.

It works well. I can set `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain virtualMachineHost myLocalDomain`.

The problem is that all other services inside the Virtual machine are not able anymore to get the cookies.

I would like to have a dynamic variable for the directive that set the cookie domain to the requesting host.
I've tried with `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain virtualMachineHost %{HTTP_HOST}` as suggested in the apache documentation but it looks like the variable is not expanded. It is treated as a string and the cookie domain is consequently set to "%{HTTP_HOST}".

Is there any way to use apache environment variables to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, and I had the same requirement for a reverse proxy application I'm running. I believe this is not possible with apache, unfortunately. on the other hand, a very easy workaround might do what we both want, see below;

Use nginx as a reverse proxy on top of your apache reverse proxy, very simple configuration
and this is what you want "proxy_cookie_domain"

```
server {
  listen 80; //or your port
  server_name *.example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://apache_proxy_servers;
    proxy_cookie_domain ~\.*$ $host; // this is your line
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Waheed. I'll try your solution.

Comment: You are welcome Antonio, I actually have implemented it on my end, works as expected